# Java AWS SDK problem with me-central-1 region

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, amazon-s3

i'm trying to use the aws sdk for java (it's not the first time and it's always worked) but i'm getting this error:

**com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to**

In my pom i have this maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.402</version>
</dependency>
```

and this is my code to instantiate the s3 client:

```
@Bean
public AmazonS3 amazonS3() {
    AWSCredentials cred = new BasicAWSCredentials(accesskey, secretkey);
    AWSCredentialsProvider credProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(cred);
    return AmazonS3Client.builder()
            .withRegion(Regions.ME_CENTRAL_1)
            //.withCredentials(credProvider)
            .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
            .build();
}
```

As you can see I tried two different AWSCredentialsProviders, but I always get the same error

Answer (score 0):

For buckets created in regions outside of us-east-1 (N. Virginia) a location constraint is required. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/create-bucket.html for more details

> LocationConstraint -> (string)
> Specifies the Region where the bucket will be created. If you don't specify a Region, the bucket is created in the US East (N. Virginia) Region (us-east-1).

Comment: unfortunately, the bucket is set up correctly

Comment: where is this exception getting thrown? Is there a larger stack trace?